# Upgrade 10.6 Server to 10.7 server error

Tags: mac-osx-server

I am trying to upgrade 2 Mac mini Servers from OS X Server 10.6 to 10.7. I get the following error:

[image]

> The additional components needed to install Mac OS X can't be found.

Googling for this message only returns a [handful of results](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22The%20additional%20components%20needed%20to%20install%20Mac%20OS%20X%20can%27t%20be%20found.%22), which aren't too helpful.

I have purchased and installed OS X Lion Server as well.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: I once made a short try to upgrade it, but gave up on it due to similar reasons. See this discussion for more stories (interesting link in the last post there). OS X Server is dead and 10.7 server is nothing but a final slap in the face of once loyal customers.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3199627

Answer (score 0):

What support do you use to install Lion ? (Recovery Partition, Recovery Assistant, InstallESD)
Have verified Tech Spec first (http://support.apple.com/kb/SP630) ?

Does not looks like a upgrade (migration) issue, but more a install support issue.

Then if you are still stuck, you make a clone
You erase and install Lion Server, then import data from the clone.